# Table Variable in SQL Server Function from Input Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to create a function that returns a column based on input from three other columns. As temporary tables are not allowed within functions, is it possible to create a table variable from three input columns?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.convert_value(
    @CustomerID VARCHAR(MAX),
    @CustomerValue VARCHAR(MAX),
    @CustomerDescription VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS BEGIN

DECLARE @CustomerTable TABLE (
    UniquePatientUID VARCHAR(MAX),
    ResultValue VARCHAR(MAX),
    PracticeDescription VARCHAR(MAX)
);

-- How can I insert @UniquePatientUID, @ResultValue and @PracticeDescription into @CustomerTable

END
```

The context of this question is that I have a SQL script that uses temporary tables and many `UPDATE` and `ALTER TABLE` statements, that I need to convert into a function. That script begins with the three columns mentioned, and adds a fourth column, `Converted_Value`, which is calculated with several hundred lines of code and manipulating temporary tables. Is there any hope here?

Comment: Inserting into a table variable is no different from any other table. But what is it you want to *do* once the rows are in your table variable? If you just want to return all three values as pass through, you could do that in line (no table variable required).

Comment: See comment on your answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table variable insert is really not different than a regular insert. Don't use temp tables. You can alter the table as well, or just declare it initially with that fourth column and allow it to be NULL.

```
INSERT INTO @CustomerTable (UniquePatientUID, ResultValue, PracticeDescription)
VALUES(@CustomerID, @CustomerValue, @CustomerDescription);
```

Don't forget to return the FLOAT.

Comment: This is very helpful, exactly what I needed! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Table Variable is a table so, you can just use `INSERT INTO ... VALUES....`

```
 INSERT INTO @CustomerTable (UniquePatientUID,ResultValue,PracticeDescription ) 
 VALUES
 (@UniquePatientUID, @ResultValue , @PracticeDescription)
```

Comment: This along with Colin G's answer helped me out, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you *need* a table variable for some specific reason, why not just work with the variables as a derived table expression? i.e.

```
;with inputs (UniquePatientUID, ResultValue, PracticeDescription) as
(
    select @UniquePatientUID, @ResultValue, @PracticeDescription
)
select *
from inputs
```

Table variables fall out of scope after the function call, and you can't pass table types in or out of functions either. So really all a table variable does here is serve as a means of place keeping that's more familiar to SQL developers. But they're not free, which is the only reason I'm curious what your use case is.

If you don't need to return them as a set or something similar, you can just interact with the variables directly too.

Comment: This is a nice answer, and to follow up on your question, after creating this table I need to perform much manipulation on that table in the form primarily of `UPDATE` and `ALTER TABLE` statements. For that reason I thought it would be easier to work with a table variable, since it allows at least `UPDATE` operations, like temp tables do. Can you work with derived table expressions in this way as well?

Comment: You've actually struck upon the deeper point around why you're having to entertain a table variable in the first place. `Functions` in SQL-land can't have "side effects". Among many other things, that means no updates or table alterations can have any permanent impact outside the scope of the function. Table variables are allowed since they die after the function call, but temp tables can persist (and thus potentially "do stuff"). SQL functions are dissimilar from what one might loosely call a function in something like Javascript or C#. What you're describing can only be done in a proc.